# How to compile C program with multiple files in Xcode

Tags: c, macos, command-line, xcode3.2

I am on a Mac running Mac OS X 10.6.3 and Xcode 3.2.1 64-Bit and I was wondering if it was possible to compile a C program with multiple `.c` files in Xcode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Sure it is.

Assuming you're starting from scratch (without an existing XCode project), do a "new project"  and choose the "Mac OS Application" -> "Command Line Tool" -> "C" project template.

That will give you a skeleton project with a template "main.c". Edit/replace "main.c" as needed, and add the rest of your .c files to the "source" group and build.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely - just add all the .c files to your project.

Comment: I think you meant 'just _add_ all the .c files' ?

Comment: OMG WHAT THE... YOUR AND MY AVATARS HAVE BEEN MESSED WITH!! THEYRE FREAKING UNICORNS?!?!??!?!

Comment: WTF THE SITE HAS BEEN HACKORD!!

Comment: I blame "OMG Ponies" for this one :-) [ or check your calendar, depending on what timezone you're in :-) ]

Comment: @David, yea i just realized this, im like "oh yea!! tomorrows april 1st" :D

Answer (score 0):

Only the last `.c` is significant. `main.c.c.c.c` will be treated as a C-language source.

Not "fooling" though, check the column of checkboxes in the project list view. It's marked with a bullseye as the header. The checkmark signifies that the source is compiled into the selected target. Unchecked boxes are the only possible problem I can think of.