# How do you add a class in your C++ directory?

Tags: c++, xcode, directory

I've been completing the exercises in a book to learn C++.

Exercise 1.20: http://www.informit.com/title/032174113 contains a copy of `Sales_item.h` in the Chapter 1 code directory. Copy that file to your working directory. Use it to write a program that reads a set of book sales transactions, writing each transaction to the standard output.

First off, the link they provided wasn't working. However, I got around this by finding the code on GitHub. However, I am extremely confused on how to add this to my directory. To be honest, I don't even know what that means? Could someone please explain how to add this code into your library?

Answer (score 0):

id doesn't say "add to your directory", it says "copy that file to your working directory". Your working directory is the directory you put all your `*.cpp` and `.h` and project files in.

Comment: Download it and place in the given directory... I don't know how to make that easier to understand. Help on browsing directories: http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20520?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Ok sorry I feel retarded.  So I download the text file and put it in the folder where my main.cc file is.  Its still giving me an error saying that it doesn't recognize the file.  What am i doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Use the `#include` preprocessor directive. It should be covered in some earlier chapter or part of the one you're reading. And yes - you got the first part right :)

Comment: This is my code:#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"
int main()
{
    Sales_item item1, item2;
    std::cin >> item1 >> item2;   // read a pair of transactions
    std::cout << item1 + item2 << std::endl; // print their sum
    return 0;
}
As you can see, i used the #include.   Please help and thanks for your patience :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557766/how-to-compile-c-program-with-multiple-files-in-xcode

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If it is what i'm thinking, do the following.

-Copy the Sales_item.h file to your working directory(probably where your code is)
-Include the Sales_item.h file in your program using:

```
       #include "Sales_item.h"
```

Comment: Sorry I feel stupid but what is a directory?  Is this just your finder where all your files in?  I put the text file I downloaded in the folder that has the main.cpp file in it and its still not recognizing it.  Please help and sorry for being new and stupid.

Comment: @user2444335 directory=folder; Include the header to your program using `#include "Sales_item.h"` then it should recognize it.